# Asp.net Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

My project's start page is Default.aspx.

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

         Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx);

    }
```

When I click the button it returns //localhost/Default.aspx/Payment.aspx instead of //localhost/Payment.aspx. Where is the problem?

Comment: have you tried Response.Redirect("~/Payment.aspx");?

Comment: @AliBaghdadi: Thats the answer. Why posted it as a comment?

Comment: Thank you @Ali, if you want, write that as an answer and i'll accept it. It's worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("~/Payment.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Payment.aspx");
```

> The tilde (~) character represents the root directory of the application in ASP.NET.